# How to prune certain weights (rather than freeze a layer) with Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to prune some connections in a deep model with Keras. These connections are in different locations and different fully-connection layers, so setting `layer.trainable=False` doesn't work for me.

1. So how to prune these connections (freeze their weights to 0 during training) in Keras? Do I need to writing my own layers and how to?
2. Does the other tools like PyTorch support this prune (or freeze) operation easily (no need to write my own layers)?

Comment: For PyTorch you just need to set: `my_layer.weight.requires_grad = False` to freeze your layer weights (same needs to be done for `my_layer.bias`).
https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.0/notes/autograd.html#excluding-subgraphs-from-backward

Comment: @blue-phoenox It seems like ```my_layer.weight.requires_grad = False``` freeze all the weights in a certain layer, but what I need is to freeze specific weights, for example, the weight of the connection between the 1st neuron in the 1st layer and the 1st neuron in the 2nd layer.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. Haven't tried this before, you could take a look at pytorch sparse, maybe this is somehow helpful. Good luck further! https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html

Answer (score 0):

This tool will be of interest to you:https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning